# "anschuldigen" oder "beschuldigen"

Tags: meaning, difference

Aus den Beispielen, die ich im Internet gefunden habe, habe ich geschlossen, dass man sich selbst:

- Ich **beschuldige** mich, dass ich dir das angetan habe.

  und andere:

  - Sie hat ihn **beschuldigt**, nicht genug aufgepasst zu haben.

  beschuldigen kann.

Also in beiden Fällen wird niemand vor Gericht zur Verantwortung gezogen - alles, was jemand getan hat, ist keine Straftat.

Aber, wenn man sagt:

- Man **beschuldigte** ihn, einen Diebstahl begangen zu haben. (Duden)
- Er **beschuldigte** sie des Mordes.

oder mit "anschuldigen":

- jemanden des Diebstahls/wegen eines Diebstahls **anschuldigen** (Duden)
- Sie sind **angeschuldigt**, den Mord begangen zu haben (Duden)

Was versteht man darunter? Ich gebe jemandem die Schuld an etwas oder ich erhebe gegen jemanden eine Anklage gegen etwas? Wann sind die beiden Verben unterschiedlich und wann austauschbar?

Was die Substantive betrifft, habe ich auf einer Internetseite gelesen, dass "Anschuldigung" öfter als "Beschuldigung" verwendet wird. Seid ihr damit einverstanden? Oder besteht zwischen den Substantiven ein wesentlicher Unterschied?

Comment: The first example would idiomatically read *Ich werfe mir vor, dir das angetan zu haben*. Since *an/be-schuldigen* both imply a formalism, which is misssing if I'm just angry with myself.

Answer (score 8):

Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch macht es m.E. keinen Unterschied, ob man das Verb „anschuldigen“ oder „beschuldigen“ verwendet.

Im juristischen Sprachgebrauch – siehe [§ 157 Strafprozessordnung (StPO)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__157.html) – unterscheidet man im Strafverfahren zwischen

- dem Beschuldigten,
- dem Angeschuldigten und
- dem Angeklagten.

**Beschuldigter** ist jemand, dem die Polizei oder Staatsanwaltschaft vorwirft, eine Straftat begangen zu haben (der Begriff ist nicht präzise definiert und wird als Oberbegriff verwendet, z.B. in [§ 136 StPO](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__136.html)). Erhebt die Staatsanwaltschaft Klage ([§ 170 StPO](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__170.html)), spricht man vom **Angeschuldigten**. Eröffnet das Gericht auf die Klageerhebung hin das Hauptverfahren ([§ 199 StPO](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__199.html); [§ 203 StPO](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stpo/__203.html)), spricht man vom **Angeklagten**.

Wenn die Begriffe in einem juristischen Kontext verwendet werden, kann man also mit ihrer Hilfe erkennen, wie weit das Strafverfahren fortgeschritten ist. Wenn man vom Angeschuldigten spricht, heißt dies, dass die *Staatsanwaltschaft* einen für Anklage ausreichenden Verdacht bejaht, das Ermittlungsverfahren abgeschlossen hat und Anklage erhoben hat. Vor Eröffnung des Hauptverfahrens muss jedoch noch das *Gericht* prüfen, ob es von einem hinreichenden Tatverdacht überzeugt ist und auch die sonstigen Voraussetzungen für die Zulässigkeit des Hauptverfahrens gegeben sind (siehe auch den Wikipedia-Eintrag zum „[Angeschuldigten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angeschuldigter)“).

Aus der Funktion dieser Substantive ergibt sich dann auch der Einsatzbereich der zugehörigen Verben: Ist das Ermittlungsverfahren noch nicht abgeschlossen, wird eine Person (lediglich) eines Delikts **beschuldigt** (aber noch nicht **angeschuldigt** und erst recht noch nicht **angeklagt**).

Comment: Es ist einfacher zu sagen "X hat Y beschuldigt", als etwas verschachtelt "angeschuldigt" zu verwenden. Gleichfalls einfacher ist *Anschuldigung* da schon ein Stopp vor dem *sch* eingebaut ist (das *n*), während *Be-schuldigung* einen Stopp braucht, da sonst die *Bschuldigung oder Pschuldigung* daraus werden könnte, wenn nicht besonders deutlich gesprochen wird. Hab ich vielleicht schlecht erklärt, aber der Punkt ist, *es gibt noch Unterschiede*.

Answer (score 0):

Sowohl die beiden Verben *beschuldigen* und *anschuldigen* als auch die daraus abgeleiteten Substantive *Beschuldigung* und *Anschuldigung* werden praktisch gleichwertig verwendet.

Man kann ein Bild gebrauchen, das den Unterschied deutlich macht: Jemanden zu *beschuldigen* bedeutet, ihm eine Schuld auf den Buckel zu laden. Wie eine Last, mit der er dann *belastet* ist. Das macht also etwas Mühe. Jemanden *anzuschuldigen* bedeutet hingegen, die Schuld irgendwo seitlich dranzustellen und dann schnell das Weite zu suchen.

Answer (score -1):

Laut Duden, wenn man angeklagt wird, wird man vor Gericht angeklagt (öffentich), wegen einer Straftat. Beschuldigen heißt, jemandem die Schuld an etwas geben. Es handelt sich nicht unbedingt um ein Straffahren, aber sowas ist nicht ausgeschlossen.  Ein Beschuldigter könnte unter Verdacht fallen, eine Straftat begangen zu haben (vielleicht wird gegen ihn ermittelt). In einem Zivilprozess nennet man einen, der verklagt wird, einen Beklagten (defendant), In Kriminalverfahren werden diejenigen,die wegen einer Strafttat von der Staatsanwaltschaft angeklagt werden, Angeklagte.(auch Defendants)

Answer (score -1):

Während die formal-juristische Bedeutung weiter oben erläutert wird, möchte ich bemerken, dass *beschuldigen* in der Alltagssprache mit *jemandem die Schuld an etwas geben* (to blame, accuse) synonym ist, also impliziert wird, durch die Bezeichnung eines Verdachts werde sofort die Schuld auferlegt. Der Begriff wäre in diesem Sinne bildlich gesprochen. Denn Schuld bedeutet im engeren Sinne die Pflicht einen Ausgleich zu leisten. In *du bist Schuld* steht "Schuld" offensichtlich für *schuldig*.

Die Anschuldigung dagegen ist der eigentliche Vorgang des Bezichtigens, Anzeigens, Proklamierens, etc. *gegen* ("an") eine Person.<sup>1</sup>

Diese Annahme ist plausibel, und gelegentlich auch wortwörtlich zu verstehen, eben dann, wenn unter gewissen Voraussetzungen die Anschuldigung schon einer Verurteilung gleich kommt. Dies aber scharf abzugrenzen ist in der Juristik durchaus sinnvoll.

Ob die Begriffe ursprünglich der Alltagssprache entstammen, bzw. ob in den ursprünglichen Rechtssystemen so scharf unterschieden wurde, sei dahingestellt. Es handelt sich hier nur um mein Sprachverständnis.

<sub>1:  Vgl. bspw. *jemanden anfahren*, oder *Angriff*. Eventuell ist aber auch "An-fang" ein bedeutender Vergleich, s. *Anfangsverdacht*.</sub>